# Href Link around an icon set as a background image not working in my menu

Tags: html

This is what the HTML looks like:

```
<ul id="navigation">
    <li>
      <a href="https://google.com">
        <div class="icon icon-user"></div>
        <div class="text">About Us</div>
      </a>
    </li>  
</ul>
```

The problem is that the image shows with the icon but when I click the image, it does not redirect me to the URL link. However it works when I insert a Javascript # link page, how can I fix this so that it redirects me to the URL when I click on the icon?

Comment: You aren't trying to run that in a frame / iframe are you? Google does not let itself appear in a frame. Your browser console will tell you more. Otherwise, this works fine ~ http://jsfiddle.net/Kxw8a/

Comment: It doesn't work on my specific sheet, I believe the problem is that the icon URL is being overshadowed or overwritten. Calling Javascript pages work perfectly but nothing I do makes the URL links work; and there are no iframes on the page. - This is more of the surrounding code of the sheet shown here, http://jsfiddle.net/rapY6/ - On my side the google.com won't run, when I click on the icon nothing happens but the Javascript #tags pop up perfectly.

Comment: In older versions of Chrome (for example) I know the browser 'unexpectedly' closed `a` tags which had `div`'s wrapped in them. Have you tried with a different internal asset, such as a `span` or `i`?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, i just add the target property for the link and it was working fine. Check my code and JSFiddle.

```
 <ul id="navigation">
    <li>
     <a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">
     <div class="icon icon-user"></div>
     <div class="text">About Us</div>
     </a>
    </li> 
 </ul>
```

[**FIDDLE LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/rapY6/3/)